# I need to extract Duration of an "endless" string

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this

```
aaa ~120 Sek. 53 Sek. ~~ bbb asdfasf aasdf asdfasdf ~600 Sek.~~ ccc ~60 Sek. 43 Sek. ~~ ddd ~240 Sek. 55 Sek. ~~
```

I have to add up all the `xxx Sek`. (which are just seconds).

Any good idea?

Regards Bruno

Comment: Just added the regex tag as this may be a useful way of doing this.

Comment: _“Any good idea?”_ - please go read [ask]. We expect you to put a bit more initial effort into your problem/question here, than just asking us for “ideas”.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do with `regex` look ahead, so you can get all the digits followed by `Sek` word. If you want to do any filtering on a matched result like 3 digits or something else then you can use [strlen()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function.

```
$re = '/\d+(?= Sek)/';
$str = 'aaa ~120 Sek. 53 Sek. ~~ bbb asdfasf aasdf asdfasdf ~600 Sek. ~~ ccc ~60 Sek. 43 Sek. ~~ ddd ~240 Sek. 55 Sek. ~~';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
#print_r($matches);
$sum = 0;
foreach ($matches as $item) {
    $sum += $item[0];
}
echo $sum;
```

**Edit:** Calculate **sum** alternatively,

```
$sum = array_reduce($matches, function(&$result, $item) {
    return $result + $item[0];
}, 0);
```

**OR**

```
$sum= array_sum(array_column($matches,0));
```

Working demo: https://3v4l.org/iQp0q

Comment: It works - if I work with the $str (like above) when I hardcode this string $str.

As soon as I enter the same string to a MySql database and retrieve it from there: The result does not work, The sum will use only 53+43. It doesn't care about 120, 600 and 60.

Comment: For all field -contents from mysql: I replaced ÄÖÜßäöü with &auml; 
Now my code works fine.

Comment: @dh1sbg glad it works now, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers